# CORS on DotCloud, 411 Length required

Tags: nginx, chunked-encoding, dotcloud, http-status-code-411

tl;dr: how do I work around "411 Length required" errors from nginx running on DotCloud?

I've got an API with CORS support deployed as Python service on DotCloud platform. When my javascript client tries to access it, browser starts with OPTIONS request, but gets back 411.

It appears nginx on DotCloud doesn't like HTTP requests with empty body. I've seen suggestions to add "Content-Length: 0" header, or try to use `chunkin` module, but I cannot do either:

- I don't control HTTP request headers that browser adds for its OPTIONS request
- I don't think I can install 3rd party nginx module on DotCloud. Even if I could, this might not even help as there is no "Transfer-encoding: chunked" header in request

Any ideas how to work around this problem?

**Update:**

Putting the following in `nginx.conf` solves my immediate problem. Similarly to chunkin, it traps 411 errors and returns canned response if request method is `OPTIONS`. Came across it [in this repo](https://github.com/titanous/graphite-on-dotcloud).

```
error_page 411 = @cors;
location @cors {
  if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Content-Type, Authorization, ...';
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age '1800';
    add_header Content-Length 0;
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200;
  }
  return 411;
}
```

It's not ideal as I'd like to handle these responses in Python code not nginx configuration. And I expect problems down the road with DELETE and HEAD requests--these don't have request body either.

Comment: I think you should give a try to chunkin. It simply handles 411 error and its that what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately chunkin is not available on dotcloud...

Comment: Seen this? https://github.com/dotcloud/nginx-on-dotcloud

Comment: dotCloud engineer here -- we're considering a potential workaround, to allow transformation of chunked requests into non-chunked requests at the upstream level. Can't give an ETA, but we're definitely thinking about it; so eventually the problem should disappear and you'll be able to get rid of the extra Nginx configuration! (Alternatively we might enable chunkin in all Nginx-related services...)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go around this issue is to not use nginx and use gunicorn instead.
Here is an example of a `dotcloud.yml` for such a configuration:

```
www:
    type: python-worker
    config:
        python_version: v2.7
    processes:
        api: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT_WWW -w 8 wsgi:app
    ports:
        www: http
```